# How can I render the ♦ (Unicode Black Diamond Suit) the same on all devices?

Tags: android, html, ios, unicode

I need to render the Black Diamond Suit (♦, U+2666) the same on multiple browsers. Unfortunately, this is an emoji as well, meaning it renders like this:

[image]

<sup>[Source](https://www.emojibase.com/emoji/2666/blackdiamondsuit)</sup>

when I want it to always render like the "browser" image (top left).

This is especially frustrating on iOS and Android because it's not rendered as black.

Unfortunately, Font Awesome doesn't include a usable replacement. The nearest is "Black lozenge", U+29EB ⧫︎ but it's a bit stretched.

Is there a way to force the mobile browser to render it like a desktop browser would?

Comment: have you tried explicitly declaring the font, font-size, and color?  I wonder if there are native values being applied in the browsers/devices.

Comment: @AdamHeeg yeah, a few elements up is `font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 15px;` I just added `color: black` and it didn't help...

Comment: Have you tried using the alternate unicode character `"\u{25C6}"` or the text version `"\u{2666}\u{FE0E}"`?

Comment: @DennisW. The first is a little squat, the second works!

Comment: @DennisW. So the second character is forcing the first to render without styling!? That's excellent!

Comment: @Tim not sure how it works, just saw there was text version in the spec at `fileformat.info`

Comment: @DennisW. Feel free to write that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the spec found on [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2666/index.htm) there is a text version of the black diamond that can be used instead:`"\u{2666}\u{FE0E}"`

Answer (score 2):

Use this in css

color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 0 black;

Answer (score 0):

2023 observation: `"\u{2666}\u{FE0E}"` doesn't seem to work on my Android Chrome - displays red diamond.

`"\u{25C6}"` does work here - black diamond is displayed on phone.
HTML code `&#x25C6;`